# ASP.NET ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider asking for smartcard

Tags: asp.net, iis, ldap, iis-express, smartcard

I am using Forms Authentication with ActiveDiretoryMembershipProvider and ASP.NET Login-Control. The problem occurs while testing locally with IIS Express.

When I first enter credentials no immediate redirect happens but instead a window asking for a smartcard repeatedly pops up. Closing this window will eventually lead to a succesful login.

This happens only the first time I call Membership.ValidateUser() after application start. Subsequent logins don't cause it.

Stepping through the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider code showed that it happens when the MembershipProvider is selected or instantiated. Dismissing the pop up will not effect the outcome of the authentication, but the application will halt until the pop up is closed.

I have read the ASP.NET Login Control and ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider code and couln't find any references to smartcards.

Therefore I think the reason for this behaviour is not in the code itself, but another event that is also triggered when I first try to connect to the AD.

What could possibly cause this behaviour? (hidden ASP.NET or IIS Express functionality?)

I don't want to use any smartcard authentication.

The popup belongs to the IIS Express Worker Process.

The only smartcard related configuration I could find was "ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication". But it is disabled in applicationhost.config.

Answer (score 0):

Current workarounds:

1. disable Smartcard Service (SCardSvr)
2. running a powershell script to close all iisexpress popups

```
@ECHO OFF
echo This script kills all iisexpress popups, and can be placed in your autostart directory
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -command "while($true) { if(get-process iisexpress) { for (1..20) { (get-process iisexpress).closemainwindow(); Start-Sleep -m 200; } }; Start-Sleep -s 5; }; PAUSE"
echo Done
PAUSE
```